# SSJS - Rows.Retrieve() return empty array

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I tried to get all rows from DE by DE name, I got an empty array.

For the test, I tried to add a new record to this DE before the read function.

**Edit: This is a Shared Data Extension**

My code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('core', '1');
    try {
        var de = DataExtension.Init("ENT.DE_NAME");
        var data = {
            status: "status",
            errorMsg: "errorMsg"
        }
        Write("add: " + de.Rows.Add(data));
        Write("<Br>");
        var rows = de.Rows.Retrieve();
        Write(Stringify(rows));
    }catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Output:

```
add: 1
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Shared Data extension, Platform and Core functions do not support the use of enterprise-level data extensions. So, you have to use a combination of SSJS and ampscript if you need.

Add another column named 'include' in your shared DE and add a default value as '1'

And try with the below code:

You can use SSJS for adding records and ampscript to retrieve records. This code will work for more than 2000 records as well.

```
   <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load('core', '1');
    try {
        var de = DataExtension.Init("ENT.Shared DE Name");
        var data = {
            status: "status",
            errorMsg: "errorMsg"
        }
        Write("add: " + de.Rows.Add(data));
        Write("<Br>");

    }catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
%%[
SET @DECount = DataExtensionRowCount('ENT.Shared DE Name')
SET @RECORDS = LookupOrderedRows("ENT.Shared DE Name", @DECount, "status asc","include","1")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@RECORDS)
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
Set @row = Row(@RECORDS,@i)
Set @value = Field(@row,"status")
Set @value2 = Field(@row,"errorMsg")
]%%
%%=v(@value)=%% <br>
%%=v(@value2)=%%
%%[
next @i
]%%
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: When I try to use the External key I get the error: "There was an error Adding the row(s).".

When I try to remove the Rows.add function I still get an empty array....

Comment: @DanielRomano I have added the above code in my instance and am getting values. 
1. Please make sure in your data extension you are adding having a column named - 'status ahd errorMsg'. 
2. Also there shouldn't be any primary key and all the fields just make it as null

Comment: Thank you for your help @razor All fields are "Nullable"... Please note it is a child BU.

Comment: @DanielRomano I have updated my answer. Please try with that one. It works in my instance. Let me know if you have any issues.